# Unwanted 303 Redirects prevent Facebook Sharing

Tags: facebook, redirect, typo3, typo3-9.x, http-status-code-303

I run a website which seems to have a problem with 303 Redirects.
The CMS is TYPO3 9.5.24.

I don't know where the redirects are coming from. Unfortunately the 303 redirects are not listed in the network tab of the console (testet Chrome, FF). Why not?

**The Problem is Facebook is not able to scrape the pages**. Their Sharing debugger (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/) tells me "URL requested a HTTP redirect, but it could not be followed."

I checked with https://www.redirect-checker.org/index.php, there I get a loop of 303 redirects.

[image: Redirect checker Screenshot]

I can view the website in any browser just fine, no problems there.
I checked `.htaccess` and the TYPO3 Backend for 303 redirects, but found nothing.
I suspected a server (nginx) misconfiguration but can't figure it out. Other websites on the same server do not have that problem.

Has anyone experienced similar problems?

Comment: The redirects should be visible in your server logs. at least two URLs would be helpful: which URL is called and then redirected to which URL.

Comment: I'd suggest to check the URL with `curl -IL https://domain.tld/foo/`. The parameter `I` just shows the response header, `L` follows the redirects. Maybe this gives you more hints about the redirects.

Answer (score 0):

Found the redirection in our custom code. Had nothing to do with Typo3.
Sorry for the confusion.
Thanks Peter Kraume, the curl check helped me to find the problem.

Appearently modern browsers ignore a 303 redirect loop, so i was not able to see anything in browser console.

Can be closed.